# Timestamp ranges not showing in Org Agenda: org-duration-to-minutes defined as void

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Version: GNU Emacs 28.2

I'm having trouble displaying timestamp ranges on the Org Agenda. For example, if I have

```
* Event
  <2023-07-29 Sat 08:00>
```

The Week-agenda correctly displays the event as

```
Week-agenda (W30):
Monday     24 July 2023 W30
Tuesday    25 July 2023
Wednesday  26 July 2023
Thursday   27 July 2023
Friday     28 July 2023
Saturday   29 July 2023
  [org-file]: 8:00...... Event
Sunday     30 July 2023
```

However, if I use a timestamp range like

```
* Event
  <2023-07-29 Sat 08:00-09:00>
```

Org Agenda displays:

```
Week-agenda (W30):
Monday     24 July 2023 W30
Tuesday    25 July 2023
Wednesday  26 July 2023
Thursday   27 July 2023
Friday     28 July 2023
```

The mode line displays "Symbol's function definition is void: org-duration-to-minutes".

I'm not sure what to do since I cannot find documentation regarding this symbol in the manual. From what I've read, it should work out of the box: https://orgmode.org/manual/Time_002dof_002dday-specifications.html

Comment: There may be an `autoload` missing in your version. Do `(load-library "org-duration")` and try again. What version of Org mode are you running?

Comment: @NickD Thank you, it works! I'm using Org mode version 9.5.5.

Comment: For a more permanent fix, you might want to add something like this to your init file: `(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda (require 'org-duration))`  - that will ensure that the `org-duration` library is loaded, after `org-agenda` itself is loaded.

Comment: I use `use-package` so I have `:init (load-library "org-duration")` in my `org` declaration.